# Excel download from Asp.Net Web API using Axios post method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, axios

I have an action which returns excel file.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Export([FromBody] QueryParameters qp)
{                
    var stream = _service.GetExcel(qp);
    var exportFileName = "MyExcel";
    return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", exportFileName);                      
}
//
public class QueryParameters
{
    public int From { get; set; }           
    public int Page { get; set; } 
    public int Size { get; set; } 
}
```

I am using react js with Axios library to make the web API calls. Now the question here is, how I can make a call to above API using axios post call which triggers the browser to download the excel returned by API and save it?

I have given below try but it seems nothing is coming in response object in axios call but I could see the excel content in browsers response under Networks tab. So it looks like the browser is getting the file content but not saving it. Any idea what I am missing, please?

```
const requestBody = {
    From: 10,
    page:2,
    Size:10
};

axios.request('POST', 'https://myexport.dev.com/export', requestBody )
.then(response => {data:response.data}) //response is comming as null here
.catch((error) => {
    //handle error
}           
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I know it might be too late for you. Just reply in case someone else needed. You can try to change your code to the following.

```
axios.request({method:'POST', url:'https://myexport.dev.com/export',
data:{someKey: someValue}, responseType: 'blob' })
.then((response) => {
   const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([responseData]));
   const link = document.createElement('a');
   link.href = url;
   link.setAttribute('download', 'fileName.xlsx');
   document.body.appendChild(link);
   link.click();
});
```